# What is the definition of canonical momentum in curved spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, field-theory, definition

For a classical field theory of a field $\phi$ defined on a flat Minkowski background with an action
$$ S_\text{flat}[\phi] = \int \mathrm{d}^n x  \mathcal{L}(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi),$$

we take the canonical momentum to be

$$ \Pi = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}},$$

where $\dot{\phi} = \partial_t \phi$ and we define the Hamiltonian via a Legendre transformation as

$$ \mathcal{H} = \Pi \dot{\phi} - \mathcal{L}.$$

If instead I had a theory defined on a curved spacetime with metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ and action

$$ S_\text{curved}[\phi, g_{\mu \nu}] = \int \mathrm{d}^n x \sqrt{-g} \mathcal{L}(\phi, \nabla_\mu \phi) $$

I am unsure how my canonical momentum, and hence Hamiltonian, is defined. Would I define my canonical momentum via

$$ \Pi = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\nabla_0 \phi)} \quad \text{or} \quad \Pi = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}} $$

where $\nabla_0$ is the time covariant derivative, and would the Hamiltonian have the same definition?

Comment: Field theory on curved spacetimes makes most sense only in those backgrounds which are globally hyperbolic - i.e. those that have a globally defined timelike Killing vector $K$. We can set up local coordinates where $K = \partial_\tau$. Then, the canonical momentum is defined w.r.t. $\tau$.

Comment: $\nabla_0\phi=\dot{\phi}$ for a scalar field $\phi$.

Comment: @Qmechanic suppose the field was a spinor field , then the two derivatives wouldn’t be the same